# Hidden Message: Hidden in The Cards

Tags: cipher, cards

The image below carry a hidden message. The image alone is not enough, you'll need to use the hints to uncover the hidden message. All the information needed to solve the puzzle is already given (as in no outside source needed).

[image: image of the cards]

Hint:

**On the first day, the first sacrifice follow his family here while the others come alone.
On the second day, the first sacrifice leads his family here while the other come alone.
On the third day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the others come alone.
On the fourth day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the others come alone.
By sacrificing the heads of all that comes, can one reach the truth.**

The final answer will be in text/ words.

Comment: **On the third day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the others come alone. On the fourth day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the others come alone...** Are you sure this wasn't a typo?

Comment: @Ruslan which part? The clue for 3rd and 4th is actually the same so the line is repeated.

Comment: @d'alar'cop ah it should've been "heads of all that comes" (I'll fix that), the line is only meant to say the last step (the first part) to find the answer.

Comment: @d'alar'cop No problem, glad you like it :)

Comment: @moonRabbit Oh, ok, thanks for clarifying! I thought that the 3rd and 4th clues repeat in the spirit of the 1st and 2nd (i.e. follows then leads) and just wanted to make sure it wasn't a mistake. Very interesting puzzle, btw!

Comment: No problem, always happy to clear things up. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spoiler:

> SEND THE JADE FAST

Each card has a name and a family

```
ES NC DD
TH ED
JD AD EH
FH AS TC
```

The days are ordered from top to bottom. The sacrifices are ordered from left to right, so on day 1, the first sacrifice is ES, second is NC, third is TD.

If a family is mentioned it should be included, otherwise left out.  If a sacrifice "follows" his family, then the family is listed first.  If the sacrifice leads his family, then the family is listed second.

> On the first day, the first sacrifice follow his family here while the
>   others come alone.

```
SE N D
```

> On the second day, the first sacrifice leads his family here while the
>   other come alone.

```
TH E
```

> On the third day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the
>   others come alone.

```
J AD E
```

> On the fourth day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while
>   the others come alone.

```
F AS T
```

Comment: Nicely done. I guess in a way the last line wasn't really need eh?

Comment: No, not really.  Nice puzzle though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, communal puzzling time again :P I'm posting this as an answer for now, simply because there's too much stuff for a comment. This has been revised to follow moonRabbit's latest comments.

First things first, the notation `(A|2-10|J|Q|K) (c|h|s|d)` for the cards is wrong. It's "much simpler" than that.

I'm now pretty convinced that the clues refer to a "day" being a row of cards, a "sacrifice" being a card, and a "family" being all matching suited cards on the board.

Now taking the clues more literally, let's see how true they ring.

> Day 1: 8 of Spades | 9 of Clubs | 2 of Diamonds
>
> Clue: The first sacrifice follow his family here while the others come alone
>
> Translation: the first card follows his suit, while the others do not

Well, we can have a quick look at the board that does indeed match - the Eight of Spades follows from the Ace of Spades, which we have elsewhere on the board. Each of the other cards is followed by another suited card (10 of Clubs, 8 of Diamonds).

Looking at the 3 other rows, the same holds true for them all.

This now gives us the following "sacrifices":

> Eight of Spades
>
> Three of Hearts
>
> Ace of Diamonds
>
> Ace of Spades

Assuming this is correct, we now have to "sacrific[e] the heads of all that come" to find the answer. That's as far as I'm up to so far.

Comment: The notation is incorrect, it's actually much simpler than that. The interpretations of "sacrificing the heads" is also incorrect. The empty gap actually doesn't mean a thing, there are only 2 cards for the second row, so I placed them like that.

Comment: @moonRabbit updated my "answer" with a re-worked interpretation, which seems to make more sense to me. Not quite followed it through completely yet, though

Comment: @moonRabbit Don't give anything else away :p

Comment: Your interpretation of their "family" is correct and the way you write the cards at the end is the closer to solving the last line. But the "sacrifices" isn't just those 4, since the texts says (I'll use the 1st day for example) "the first sacrifice" which means 2 other cards are also sacrifice.

Comment: @d'alar'cop ah, I was posting when I noticed your message ^^;

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation.  Each row in the picture is a day.  So the first clue is:

> On the first day, the first sacrifice follow his family here while the others come alone.

That row is: `8s 9c 2d`

Assuming we are reading left to right, `8s` cannot be the sacrifice since the sacrifice must `follow his family`.  So say `9c` is the sacrifice and `8s` is his family and `2d` is one of the others.  Alternatively, `2d` could be the sacrifice, `9c` his family, and `8s` either one of the others, or part of the family.

The next clue is:

> On the second day, the first sacrifice leads his family here while the other come alone.

That row is:`3h _ 8d`

So, one interpretation would be that `3h` is the sacrifice leading his family (none), and `8d` is the other.

The third clue:

> On the third day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the others come alone.

The row is: `Jh Ad 8h`

The `Jh` must be the first sacrifice, and `Ad` the second, while `8h` is his family.

The last clue is:

> On the fourth day, the second sacrifice leads his family here while the others come alone.

It's row is: `5h As 10c`

This is the same as the previous clue, so the `5h` is the first sacrifice, the `As` is the second, and his family is the `10c`.

The final part of the hint reads:

> By sacrificing the heads all that comes, can one reach the truth.

So, the sacrifices are: `9c 3h Jh Ad 5h Ah`.

If we remove the heads of these (i.e. the number) in the original picture, you will have:

```
8s  c 2d
 h  _ 8d
 h  d 8h
 h  s 10c
```

... and this is where I get stuck...

Comment: This is the same conclusion I reached, figuring that by taking cards out, I could make a letter with the remaining pattern. Nope.

Comment: @generalcrispy What about in some form of leet speak?

Comment: Not even that... removing a card from some of the proposed locations doesn't produce a letter or a digit or a recognizable picture.

Comment: Unfortunately, the other problem I have with the hint is that it's sort of broken English, no offense to moonRabbit... but it's incredibly cryptic and hard to understand.

Comment: The interpretations for what the "family" is and "sacrificing the heads" is incorrect (I wonder if the word "sacrificing" is too confusing...)

Comment: @generalcrispy the hints is like that because I wanted to go for the "feel" of fantasy to it (you know like how Yoda speaks). Though that doesn't have anything to do with the answer itself, I just like the fantasy wordplay.